# whats is the Chernoff bound for an uniform distribution variable

Tags: calculus, probability, discrete-mathematics, inequality, distribution-tails

Let $X$ be an uniform random variable between $[0,K]$. I want to find an upper bound for a state that $X> \alpha$. So I have used blow Chernoff bound:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X\ge \alpha)&\le \frac{\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]}{e^{\alpha t}}
\end{align*}

And after calculation, I have found the blow equation :

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X\ge \alpha)&\le \frac{e^{t}(\frac{1-e^{tk}}{1-e^t})}{k.e^{\alpha t}}
\end{align*}

But, what is the simply form of this equation ? is it possible to write or approximate that based on a $e$ like $e^\beta$ which $\beta$ is based on $\alpha$ and $k$?

Comment: Not to burst your bubble, but why do you need an upper bound for $\mathbb P(X\geqslant a)$ when this quantity ($K-\alpha$) can readily be computed from the distribution?

Comment: I want to show reliability and show that the possibility of being greater than alpha is so small for big k, so we can eliminate this area. @Math1000